# Apache- 403 forbidden

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions

I have configured Apache to use the `UserDir` part so I can create users on

`http://ip.add.re.ss/~username/` where this refers to `/home/username/public_html`

The problem is,when I go to the above URL, I get a 403 forbidden.

I have given the `/home/username/public_html` folder to be writable to check, but I cannot see why this would be forbidden.

Am i missing anything possibly in Apache or user permissions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

/home/username should be "executable" by the apache process, the executable bit allows to change to that directory. /home/username/public_html and all below should be readable and executable by the apache process. It should not be writable unless there is an application specific need.

So this should do the trick:

```
chmod a+x /home/username
chmod -R a+rx /home/username/public_html
```

Try specifying full url to the file, for example: http://ip.add.re.ss/~username/mydoc.html Otherwise you willbe relying on default index. Also if you are using SELinux you may be having trouble with its restrictions, do a quick test changing it to *permisive*:

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html

Comment: That still gives me a 403 forbidden.

Comment: Ok, I have changed to permissive and i have added an index.php file. I am still getting a 403 forbidden; `You don't have permission to access /~username/index.php on this server.` I've even tried to set it disabled in the SELinux config

Comment: Could you please post UserDir relative config extract and ls -ldF {/home,/home/username,/home/username/public_html,/home/username/public_html/index.php} ? Also, does error_log say anything relevant ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it looked like: `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/username*` seemed to do the trick and it is now accessible!